# Eloquent column list by key with array as values?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I can do this with Eloquent:

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title', 'name');
```

But is there a way to make Eloquent fetch an array of values for each distinct key instead of just one column?

For instance, something like the following:

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->lists(['*', DB:raw('COALESCE(value, default_value)')], 'name');
```

Comment: Instead of lists, have you checked `select` ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't produce key value pairs like list() does.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use the [`keyBy`](http://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-keyby) method:

```
$roles = Role::all()->keyBy('name');
```

---

If you're not using Eloquent, you can create a collection on your own:

```
$roles = collect(DB::table('roles')->get())->keyBy('name');
```

---

If you're using Laravel 5.3+, the query builder now actually returns a collection, so there's no need to manually wrap it in a collection again:

```
$roles = DB::table('roles')->get()->keyBy('name');
```

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test out 4.2 yet but it will be in my next project. This looks like a very simple solution and I'm glad to see this was implemented.

Comment: @eComEvo - [I personally implemented it](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4828) just for you :)

Comment: Note: This still uses foreach loop inside, so for performance it won't make a big difference, it'll only be more Laravel way.

Comment: In Laravel 5.1 in second case it doesn't work, laravel says all() method is not defined. I used get() instead

Comment: In 5.4, if you're using keyBy with toArray(), you need to call get(), keyBy() and then toArray(). Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 32):

If you need a `key/value` array, since `Laravel 5.1` you can use `pluck`. This way you can indicate which attributes you want to use as a `value` and as a `key`.

```
$plucked = MyModel::all()->pluck(
  'MyNameAttribute', 
  'MyIDAttribute'
);

return $plucked->all();
```

You will get an array as follow:

```
array:3 [▼
   1 => "My MyNameAttribute value"
   2 => "Lalalala"
   3 => "Oh!"
]
```

Comment: why `pluck(id,name)` gives `[name=> id]` instead of `[id=>name]`?

Comment: @San Its a good answer (I asked myself the same) This is becase the first parameter of `pluck` is for assign the array value, so, when you use the second parameter, the second parameter specify the ID of the array. See this: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_pluck

Comment: @tomloprod Your given solution in laravel 8.x but I want to concat 2 columns/fields values and want to use in selectbox. I have tried `$plucked = VehicleBrand::all()->pluck(
                DB::raw('concat(vb_brand_name," (",vb_brand_code,")") as vb_brand_name'),
                'vb_id',
            );` but this is not working. any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You may try something like this:

```
$roles = array();
array_map(function($item) use (&$roles) {
    $roles[$item->id] = (Array)$item; // object to array
}, DB::table('roles')->get());
```

If you want to get an `Object` instead of an `Array` as value then just remove the `(Array)`.

**Alternative:** Using `Eloquent` model (Instead of `DB::table`):

```
$roles = array();
array_map(function($item) use (&$roles) {
    $roles[$item['id']] = $item;
}, Role::all()->toArray());
```

**Another Alternative:** Using `Collection::map()` method:

```
$roles = array();
Role::all()->map(function($item) use(&$roles) {
    $roles[$item->id] = $item->toArray();
});
```

Comment: Was hoping there was a built-in method I was just missing in the docs but this will do. Cleaner than the foreach loop I was originally using. :)